# If I have relation R(A,B,C,D,E) and the FDs are A -> C, AB -> D, CD -> E, is E fully functional dependent on AB?

Tags: database, database-design, normalization, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

Let's say we have relation R(A,B,C,D,E)

The FDs are:
 
A -> C
AB -> D
CD -> E

I know that the key is AB.

My question is: 
*Is E fully or partially dependent on AB?*

I think it's fully dependent, since AB determines E if I use FD inference rules. But, my coworker says that E is partially dependent on AB since C is partially dependent on AB. What is the correct one?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's **fully dependent** on AB because you don't have a dependency (even transitive one) `A->E` or `B->E`. In practical terms it means: if I tell you the value of `A` **or** `B` you couldn't tell me the value of `E` - you need **both** values to deduce the value. Take a look at [this short page on functional dependencies:](http://www.jkinfoline.com/functional-dependency.html)

> Y is fully functionally dependent on X and there should not be any Z→Y, Where Z is a proper subset of X.

In this context `A` or `B` would be the subsets.

Looking your whole  relation in a bigger picture it seems like a theoretical construct. At least it would be poorly designed:

- `CD -> E` **breaks the 3rd normal form**
- `A -> C` **breaks the 2nd normal form - `C` IS partially dependent on `AB`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Simo. I really appreciate It. Case closed. ;)